# Rstudio sometimes freezes a few seconds after opening or entering RMD files

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio

Rstudio intermittently freezes a few seconds after opening an RMD file, or (in cases where the RMD file was loaded on startup), after making it the active thing in the viewer.  Deleting/replacing the .nd file associated with the rmd does not prevent this.  However, opening the RMD in another text editor (such as Sublime) and copying all text to a new file which is then saved as an RMD does.  However, as soon as the file is saved in Rstudio and opened again, the problem may recur.

Is there a workaround or solution to this issue?

Comment: If I start a new file (as if it were an R file) instead of a new RMarkdown file, code, and save it as RMD, I have constant issues like this. Any chance that's what you did?